# PayPal integration with PHP: which API and credentials to use?

Tags: paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal api with PHP compared to the old button form that I have used to date on my sites. But there is one thing that is not clear to me, is it more correct to integrate paypal with client_id and secret or through the codes provided in the account panel (api username, api password and signature)? I followed the REST API integration guide (version 2) but they require client_id and secret. So what is the data in the account panel for? Anyone can clarify my ideas? Thank you

Comment: Both authentications are valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API username, password, and signature is used by the classic NVP/SOAP APIs, which are much older than the REST API. They exist only for backwards compatibility with old shopping cart software and such integrations.

The v2/checkout/orders API should be used for current [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) integrations. Pair two routes on your server (one for create order, one for capture order) that return/output only JSON data (never any HTML or text) with [this JS approval flow](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server).

Comment: I am currently using PHP and cURL to request an access token endpoint 
/v1/oauth2/token

Then I create an order using 
/v2/checkout/orders

and finally on the return page for confirmation I make the call 
/v2/checkout/orders/[order_id]/capture

The thing that seems strange to me is that the generation of the access token needed for the other calls uses the endpoint /v1/

Answer (score -1):

I would go with JS SDK [inline integration](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client) - requires `client-id` only and is more flexible than checkout buttons. Also creates nice user experience as if staying on the page (no redirects to 3rd party site). See all [demos here](https://demo.paypal.com/us/demo/home).

```
paypal.Buttons({

    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            // note: custom_id (127 chars) will be passed later back in capture
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: amtDue.toFixed(2),
                    currency: 'EUR'
                },
                description : description,
                custom_id : '<?= $encryptedPaymentData ?>'
            }]
        });
    },

    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        $("#global-spinner").show();
        // set custom capture handler
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/paypal/success",
                data: ({
                    details : details,
                    ad : amtDue,
                    desc : description,
                    _token : '<?= $csrf ?>'
                }),
                success: function(resp) {
                    $("#global-spinner").hide();
                    window.showThankYou(); // some "thank you" function
                },
                error: function() {
                    $("#global-spinner").hide();
                    alert("Connection error.");
                }
            });
        });
    },

    onError:  function (err) {
        // some custom function - send error data to server logger
        window.handlePaypalError(err, description, amtDue);
    }

}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Comment: Yes, use the JS SDK for payer approval instead of redirecting. But create and capture the order on the server via API if the result needs to be recorded in a database. So, the secret will also be used.

Comment: @PrestonPHX I added code sample, no secret needed at all.

Comment: Completing a payment on the client side with actions.order.create/capture should never post to a server after the fact, this is relying on the payer's browser to complete the process which can be interrupted for any number of reasons. Please remove this answer as it should never be used in production.

Comment: As for server side security can be used CSRF verification, filtering user input, checking against custom_id, or even created DB record before payment create. There are number of ways how to securely process response. Security tutorial e.g. https://docs.php.earth/security/intro., though security is out of question scope. As for interruption - sure, any request can be any time interrupted theoretically. That's why Paypal will independently notify by emails both parties about processed transaction.

Comment: A proper API-based capture integration is for reliability and robustness. Emails do not scale and require additional manual monitoring, they are not an excuse or crutch for bad design. Payment systems' business/fulfillment/accounting operations should not depend on the client actor when there is no reason for them to

Comment: Also forgot to mention that apart from reliability, security is also an issue here because regardless of CSRF verification there is no server-side verification that a payment actually completed. With no use of the PayPal capture API, the client can simply spoof the event completely.